# Draw over a bitmap larger than screen

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I want to paint over a bitmap that is larger than my screen, and then save it.

Image size (landscape) is 1080 x 1776 (Nexus 5), while bitmap image is 3264 x 2448.

The image is correctly scaled to fit the screen, using my activity xml file:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:id="@+id/ivPicture"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

If I draw a point on the center of the screen, the drawn point is not under my finger, but it is some pixel left/up.

Drawing a rectangle (from edge to edge of the screen) results in scaled rectangle, like image attached:
[image]

Seems some proportion problem, but I can't figure it out, this the relevant part of code.

```
public void loadImage(Uri imageFileUri) {

    /*

      ivPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPicture);
      Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
      Point size = new Point();
      display.getSize(size);
      displayWidth = size.x;
      displayHeight = size.y;

      screen size: 1794 x 1080
      bitmap size: 3264 x 2448
    * */
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(imageFileUri);

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, bmpFactoryOptions);

        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

        alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
        Log.d(TAG, "screen size: " + displayWidth + " x " + displayHeight);
        Log.d(TAG, "bitmap size: " + bmp.getWidth() + " x " + bmp.getHeight());

        canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
        matrix = new Matrix();

        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);

        ivPicture.setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap);
        ivPicture.setOnTouchListener(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
    }
}


public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downx = event.getX();
            downy = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            upx = event.getX();
            upy = event.getY();
            canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
            ivPicture.invalidate();
            downx = upx;
            downy = upy;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upx = event.getX();
            upy = event.getY();
            canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
            ivPicture.invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I guess I've encountered a math problem, how can I draw exactly over the image?